# Excel - Retain Values Only Up to Limit Based on Column Criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel I have 100,000 rows with a column of bird species and another column for the city where it was spotted.

[image]

There are roughly 150 cities. Some cities are represented in thousands of rows and some only have a handful. What I'd like to end up with is a new list that only retains up to 1,000 rows worth of the city in column B. Say New York has 5,000 sightings, Boston has 4,000, and Minneapolis has 300. I'd like the new list to only contain 1,000 rows of New York, 1,000 of Boston, and all of the Minneapolis rows as there are fewer than 1,000.

Can Excel do this? I was trying, and failing, something with COUNTIF, RAND, and RANK but I'm not a daily Excel driver. I would normally reach for SQL or .py here, but the lovely people that will need to do this regularly will be doing it in Excel. Could there be something simple where the value in col B occurrence is counted and then numbered sequentially, sorted, and then delete any values over 1,000?

Comment: Use a helper column with `=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)>1000,"ignore","list")` and filter on that

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thanks for the reply! Assuming you mean something like:

`=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$100000,G2)>1000,"ignore","list")`

wouldn't this label _every_ row for any city with over 1000 occurrences **ignore**? It would seem like the helper column would need be counting another column where you would produce a count that increments up for each occurrence. Like:

Robin | Boston | 1
Eagle | Boston | 2

Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, if you populate my formula down a helper column (notice the use of absolute vs relative cell references), it will only count instances in the lines above the current line

Answer (score 0):

First, declare your dataset as a "table" (Insert Table). Name it `Dataset`. The name must be consistent with the following query.

Then, Data / Get data / From other sources / empty query.

You are in the PowerQuery editor.

Use Advanced Query, then type:

```ocaml
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Dataset"]}[Content],
    Typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"bird", type text}, {"city", type text}}),
    Grouped = Table.Group(Typed, {"city"}, {{"Group", each _, type table [bird=nullable text, city=nullable text]}}),
    FirstN = Table.AddColumn(Grouped, "FirstN", each Table.FirstN([Group],1000)),
    Combined = Table.Combine(FirstN[FirstN])
in
    Combined
```

OK. Then PowerQuery displays the preview. Close and load (the top-left button) and the result of the query is put in a new tab.

If you change the Dataset, go to the result, right-click, Actualise.

You see on the `FirstN =` line, the 1000 threshold, and on `Source =` line, the name of your table.

Note: the query groups the lines per city. A little more complex query preserve the initial order:

```ocaml
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Dataset"]}[Content],
    Typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"bird", type text}, {"city", type text}}),
    Indexed = Table.AddIndexColumn(Typed, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    Grouped = Table.Group(Indexed, {"city"}, {{"Group", each _, type table [bird=nullable text, city=nullable text]}}),
    FirstN = Table.AddColumn(Grouped, "FirstN", each Table.FirstN([Group],1000)),
    Combined = Table.Combine(FirstN[FirstN]),
    Sorted = Table.Sort(Combined,{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    NoIndex = Table.RemoveColumns(Sorted,{"Index"})
in
    NoIndex
```

Comment: Thanks Frédéric. After trying this, the table returned by the query has same number of rows as the original dataset. I see the 1000 criteria in the query, but it doesn't appear to having an impact on the output.

Comment: Curious, I have debugged with 4 (and a little dataset), it works